# How to delete logs(NLog)?

Tags: logging, nlog

I have some trouble with Nlog.config, it doesn't delete old logs file.

```
  <target
    name="infoLog"
    xsi:type="File"
    fileName="${logDir}/info.{#}.txt"
    layout="${info}"
    archiveFileName="${logDir}/Log.info.{#}.txt"
    archiveEvery="day"
    archiveNumbering="Rolling"
    maxArchiveFiles="2"
    concurrentWrites="true" />

 <target
  name="errorLog"
  xsi:type="File"
  fileName="${logDir}/error.{#}.txt"
  layout="${error}"
  archiveFileName="${logDir}/Log.error.{#}.txt"
  archiveEvery="Day"
  archiveNumbering="Rolling"
  maxArchiveFiles="2"
  concurrentWrites="true" />
```

What i do wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Check the internal log and otherwise post it, including the full config

Answer (score 1):

There is an optional attribute

> deleteOldFileOnStartup

For your reference, you can check it [here](http://nlog-project.org/documentation/v2.0.1/html/P_NLog_Targets_FileTarget_DeleteOldFileOnStartup.htm).

Sample:

```
 <target xsi:type="File"
            name="target1"
            fileName="C:\logs\CsvImporter.log"
            layout="${date}|${level:uppercase=true}|${message}${onexception:${newline}${exception:format=tostring}}|${logger}|${all-event-properties}"
            deleteOldFileOnStartup="true"/>
```